# Submit a List from View to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

can anyone please show me the code for posting a list on button click from view to controller in mvc3-asp. i have a list in which one of the list element is check box.at first i have to select some of the values from list then submit it to save the selected values only.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is two broad to answer. So i will give you a generic example which you need to customize according to your scenario.

Assuming your view is to assign some tasks to users. Each user can be assigned to one ore more tasks.

So i will create a viewmodel like this.

```
public class UserViewModel 
{
  public int UserId { set;get;}
  public string Name { set;get;}
  public List<Task> Tasks { set;get;}
  public UserViewModel()
  {
     Tasks=new List<UserTask>();
  }      
}
public class UserTask
{
  public int ID { set;get;}
  public string Name { set;get;}      
  public bool IsSelected { set;get;}
}
```

Now in your `GET` action, you create an object of UserViewModel and set the Tasks property to a list of available taks (from your database may be)

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
  var vm=new UserViewModel();
  vm.Tasks=GetAvailableTasks();
  return View(vm);
}
```

Assuming `GetAvailableTasks` is a method which returns a list of `UserTask` objects.

Now create an editor templates. Go to your `~/Views/YourControllerName` folder and create a folder called `EditorTemplates`. Add a new view to the newly created folder and give name as `Task.cshtml`. Add the below code to that

```
@model YourNameSpace.UserTask
<p>
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsSelected)  Model.Name
   @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ID)
</p>
```

Now go back to your main view and use `EditorFor` helper method to bring the EditorTemplate.

```
@model YourNamespace.UserViewModel
<h2>Quiz 24</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Tasks)
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

Now when the form gets submitted, you can get the selected checkbox values like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(UserViewModel model)
{
   List<int> taskIds=new List<int>();
   foreach (var task in model.Tasks)
   {
     if (task.IsSelected)
     {
       //you can get the selected task id's here. 
       taskIds.Add(task.ID);    
     }
   } 
   //to do : save and redirect (PRG pattern)
}
```

[Here](http://www.techiesweb.net/radio-button-list-in-asp-net-mvc) is a blog post explaining how to use EditorTemplates to handle collections on form submit. the post is showing an example to handle radio buttons.

Comment: Razor will rebuilt ListOf / Enumrations if you include the Index of the List and the PrimaryKey / ForeignKey of the Object, wihtout the need of rebuilding it manually on the POST controller action. A bit of a hidden gem - but also MVC is not meant to work like this, as each entity should be edited separately on its own form and view. But... clearly there are good use cases that demonstrate the need for this anyway...

Comment: updated link to blog post... https://techiesweb.net/2012/10/12/radio-button-list-in-asp-net-mvc.html

Answer (score 5):

You can actually skip all this rebuilding in the controller. Razor can rebuild the list of any object using a single form. You just need to fallback to the old `for` and assign a unique name, as well as include the primary key for that collection.

On postback razor will rebuild your `ViewModel` with the modified list without any extra work.

[image]

In the markup it looks something like this

[image]

And in the controller after posting back the model is rebuilt with the new data the user has entered, and also lazyBound to ForeignKey models!

[image]

Using checkboxes or radio inputs it's slightly different. The problem is that when a checkbox is not ticked, browsers do NOT submit it back, and the model will NOT rebuild. This is not a shortfall of VS but an intended implementation of HTML1 that still lives in HTML5!

If this happens the Index Out of Bounds will occur. So you have include a hidden field for checkboxes with a value of false before the Input Box (if a user checks it it will overwrite the false to true)

But if you are using a StronglyTyped model, like in my case, any check boxes evaluated to null are automatically set to false, known as the default value for a boolean as defined in the C# specification.

Comment: This should be the answer, im using mvc 4 and the selected answer did not worked for me. This fits perfectly

Comment: Im glad it worked for you. It is one of those hidden gems or advanced techniques you can use. You cant accept the answer but please up vote if it has helped you. Thanks

Comment: I accidently down-voted this question so to anyone who looks at this, there's nothing I feel is wrong with this, just ignore that!

Comment: You can change your vote now. I edited my answer and fixed typos and stuff.