# how to save multiple values in the same property member in one post?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
public class Customer
{
  public Customer()
  {
    ContactNumbers = new HashSet<ContactNumber>();
  }

  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<ContactNumber> ContactNumbers { get; set; }
  -- remove some code for brevity --
}

public class ContactNumber
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int CustomerId { get; set; }
  public string Number { get; set; }

  public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Hi. I have this scenario a customer has many contact numbers. So what I did is in the `create view`. I put a `javascript` to manipulate the `textbox` for contact numbers. Something like..

```
$(".add-contact-trigger").click(function() {
   $(".contact-number-container").append("<div><input type=\"text\" /></div>");
});
```

So that every time they hit the button, it will generate a `textbox` for `contact number`.

Now, my problem is.. How can I submit the form in one post say, they have multiple contact number? I can only do one contact number for each post. Is there a way to save all the inputed contact number with one post?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using javascript to generate fields, for telephone numbers to be read in controller you need to use following syntax.

```
   <input type="text" name="ContactNumbers[0].Number">
   <input type="text" name="ContactNumbers[1].Number">
   <input type="text" name="ContactNumbers[2].Number">
```

It will get you numbers with empty values for `Id`, `CustomerId` and `Customer`. If you want these values to come back from view too, you can use hidden fields, where your javacript is going to enter them into hidden field value

```
 <input type="hidden" name="ContactNumbers[0].CustomerId" value="1234" >
```

[Conventional way to handle this problem is described here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888248/submit-a-list-from-view-to-controller)

Comment: Never thought about getting back the values again. Thanks mate. Think you can show demo for it? It would be great for reference ;)